# Import of bs4 or BeautifulSoup4 "unresolved" in PyCharm. Installation is fine

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pycharm, python-import, python-3.7

I want to use the BeautifulSoup4 in PyCharm 2018.3.2. Problem is, "bs4" and "BeautifulSoup"/"BeautifulSoup4" is underlined red in PyCharm when writing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup (or BeautifulSoup4)
```

Nothing else fails to import, only this module. The red underlining tells me the same for "bs4" and "BeautifulSoup(4)":

"Unresolved reference 'bs4' less... (Ctrl+F1)

Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items"

When I run PyCharm the error says:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'"

In cmd pip3 has installed everything correctly. Had to uninstall and install several times just to be sure. Atm it looks like this after installation:

[Python cmd. Not in administation mode here, but tried that too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAnup.jpg)

Also, this:

```
pip check bs4
pip check beautifulsoup4
```

says: "No broken requirements found."

I'm fairly new to python, but I've searched the web for answers but found nothing with the "unresolved reference".
Thought maybe the path was to blame, but recently installed requests and the modules are placed in the same folder in my archive so PyCharm should be able to find bs4 when it's able to find requests.

Comment: I should be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily install `BeautifulSoup4` from inside PyCharm.

First go to `File` >> `Settings`.

[image]

Then on the left side scroll down, expand the `Project` entry and click on `Project Interpreter`.

[image]

Now you can verify the settings on the right side of the window. For example, what packages are installed and which interpreter version is currently set.

*Note: If you have several interpreters with different versions installed, make sure you've selected the right interpreter.*

On the right side click on the <kbd>+</kbd> symbol (add package). In the search input line type `beautifulsoup4` and click on it in the list below.

[image]

Finally at the bottom click on `Install Package` and wait for the promt that it has installed successfully.

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't change anything with the red lining. The thing is PyCharm can't get ahold of the bs4

Comment: Ah okay then. Have you already tried installing Beautifulsoup via `pip install bs4 --user`? (Then reload PyCharm by closing and reopening) Btw. What OS are you running?

Comment: No, but tried the --user right now, and it only says "Requirement already satisfied:" for bs4, beautifulsoup4 and soupsieve. I got Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

Comment: @Sosofofie I've updated my answer. This should work for you.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Can I use the same method whenever for whatever module? Should I, or should I do it "the traditional way"?

Comment: @Sosofofie Glad to hear that. Yes you can do that to every package available in PyPI (installable via `pip`). I'd recommend to familiarize with managing environments, then you should be able to do it the "traditional" way without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience that Pycharm has something against bs4. This might not work for everyone, but to solve it once and for all, I installed bs4 within my base interpreter (using Powershell) where I have Django and a few other modules installed. That way, when I create a new project with a new virtualenv in Pycharm, and I tell it, as I usually do, to "inherit global site-packages," bs4 comes along for the ride. I hope this helps someone.